# Laravel Polymorphic Relationships Issue

Tags: laravel, polymorphism, laravel-8

I'm trying to take advantage of the Laravel's Polymorphic Relationships

I'm building an app where I have 3 tables: `products`, `expenses` and `hunts`.

Each product, expense or hunt belongs to a category. I used to have 3 other different tables `product_categories`, `expenses_categories` and `hunts_categories` but I didn't like doing it this way so I did a little bit of research and found about this Polimorphic Relationships thing but I'm not really sure how to use it.

I've create a new `category` table with the following columns

```
$table->id();
$table->string('name');
$table->integer('categorizable_id');
$table->string('categorizable_type');
$table->foreignId('icon_id')->constrained();
```

My models looks like

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function category () {
        return $this->morphOne(Category::class, 'categorizable');
    }
}

class Expense extends Model
{
    public function category () {
        return $this->morphOne(Category::class, 'categorizable');
    }
}

class Hunt extends Model
{
    public function category () {
        return $this->morphOne(Category::class, 'categorizable');
    }
}

class Category extends Model
{
    public function icon () {
        return $this->belongsTo(Icon::class);
    }

    public function categorizable () {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

I only want 5 categories for the `expenses` table so I'm seeding them directly to the database but products categories and hunt categories are created by the user

In my `CategorySeeder.php` file I have the following function

```
public function run()
    {
        DB::table('categories')->insert([
            ['name' => 'Advertising', 'icon_id' => 1, 'categorizable_id' => ?, 'categorizable_type' => 'App\Models\Expense'],
            ['name' => 'Utilities', 'icon_id' => 2],
            ['name' => 'Shopping', 'icon_id' => 3],
            ['name' => 'Payroll', 'icon_id' => 4],
            ['name' => 'Other', 'icon_id' => 5]
        ]);
    }
```

Since I want those categories before creating any expense. What should I do with `categorizable_id` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use polymorphic relationships for this. You can simply have a categories table:

```php
$table->id();
$table->string('name');
$table->foreignId('icon_id')->constrained();
```

And then have a `category_id` column on your `product`, `expenses`, and `hunts` tables:

```php
$table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained();
```

Each of your `Product`, `Expense`, and `Hunt` models would have a `category` method:

```php
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

And then your `Category` model could have something like this:

```php
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}

public function expenses()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Expense::class);
}

public function hunts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Hunt::class);
}
```

A polymorphic relationship would be useful if you had a `Note` model, for example, which could belong to either a product or an expense. In that case, you would have the columns `notable_type` and `notable_id` on your `notes` table, and then use `morphOne` on your `Product` and `Expense` models.

Comment: That makes sense! but I also need to select different categories for different models. Like when I'm in the expense view I only want to select expenses categories. Do I have to add a type column in my categories table? If yes what data type should it be or is there any other way to tell apart what categories belong to what model?

Comment: In that case, you could just add a `type` column and then use a query like `SELECT * FROM categories WHERE type = 'App\\Models\\Expense'`